# Iterate and loop through certain nested values to use within JSON Data and Request URLs

Tags: python, arrays, loops, if-statement, nested

```
i_ucprice = [[id, price], [id, price], [id, price], [id, price]]

    for ids in id_ucprice:
        post_data = {
            'price': ids[1],
            'overpriced_email_price_change': False,
            'apply_to_all': False,
            }
        for i in range(ids[0]):
            response = requests.post('api{ids[0]}/pricing', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=post_data)
            update_data = json.loads(response.text)
            print(update_data)
            response_price = update_data['priceCents']
            r_item = update_data['name']
            r_id = update_data['id']
            ids[0]

        if response_price == ids[1]:
            print(style.MAGENTA + f'[{datetime.now()}] => Updated Price: {response_price/100:.2f} | ID: {r_id} | Item: {r_item}')
```

I have an nested list that works as `[[id, price], [id, price], [id, price], [id, price]]` and I need to iterate through the `[0]` and the `[1]` value to use in the request url and json data respectively. I can't get the variable to be used in the request url but the json data seems to work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried making the url f-string?

```
        response = requests.post(f'api{ids[0]}/pricing', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=post_data)
```

Comment: Ugh, another time I made this error and didn't even realize. But my issue now is it's not looping through each value just the first multiple times.

Comment: you have array i_ucprice but loop through id_ucprice. align them. to both be i_ucprice or id_ucprice.